# How do I determine if any combination of the sum of a set of values is equal to a certain value?

Tags: c#, algorithm, excel, vba

I have a set of values below. What I need to find out is if any combination of these value's sums a certain value (46,134.77 in this case). What is the best way to figure this out? Of course it would take hours to do it manually.

And I would need to know what the combination is if it returned true. I could set this up in Excel VBA, or a C# app. Whatever would work. I just have no clue how to get there.

```
 125.00 
 1,000.00 
 1,039.36 
 1,171.60 
 1,200.00 
 1,320.00 
 1,680.00 
 1,757.20 
 1,768.80 
 1,970.00 
 2,231.25 
 2,300.00 
 2,369.25 
 2,589.20 
 2,720.00 
 2,887.50 
 3,000.00 
 3,085.00 
 3,142.60 
 3,174.40 
 3,742.70 
 3,847.20 
 5,609.25 
 5,881.05 
 12,240.48 
 14,112.00 
 29,318.07 
 32,551.80
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403865/algorithm-to-sum-up-a-list-of-numbers-for-all-combinations

Comment: Sounds like a binary search tree where the value of each node is the sum of nodes above when true.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm to find which numbers from a list of size n sum to another number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83547/algorithm-to-find-which-numbers-from-a-list-of-size-n-sum-to-another-number)

Comment: You and everyone else would like a solution to this problem. This waiter, for example: http://xkcd.com/287/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost precisely a bounded [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), one of the most well-studied computation problems in [history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#History). Locally:

- [Algorithm to find which numbers from a list of size n sum to another number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83547/algorithm-to-find-which-numbers-from-a-list-of-size-n-sum-to-another-number)

---

**[NP Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Np_complete)** means you should get ready to write a **giant loop** summing up every (or nearly every) combination of numbers.

I'd recommend not doing this by hand. Several hours is a *gross* underestimation. **It would take your whole life.** For example there are over 40 million combinations of 14 numbers when choosing from a pool of 28. (That's just the 14's).

Comment: Almost, at least -- the knapsack problem is, strictly speaking, to find the **closest** combination which doesn't exceed the target.

Answer (score 6):

As already mentioned in paislee's answer, this is a variation on the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). In fact, this specific problem is called the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), and like the knapsack problem, it is NP-complete.

The linked Wikipedia page shows how to solve the problem using dynamic programming, but note that due to its NP completeness it will always be slow/impossible to solve if you make your list of integers too large.

Here are some more related SO questions:

- [Subset sum Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355955/subset-sum-algorithm)
- [Subset Sum algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355955/subset-sum-algorithm)
- [Optimizing subset sum implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236684/optimizing-subset-sum-implementation)

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is a variant of the [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). It's computationally Hard to solve effectively, but for a set this small it's feasible.

The exact combination of numbers for this specific input is:

```
29,318.07 + 5,881.05 + 3,174.40 + 3,085.00 + 2,231.25 + 1,320.00 + 1,000.00 + 125.00
```

I used the following Perl script to determine this solution:

```
sub knapsack {
    my ($target, $path, @vals) = @_;
    if ($target == 0) {
        print "Got it: @$path\n";
        exit;
    }
    while (my $val = pop @vals) {
        next if $val > $target;
        knapsack($target - $val, [@$path, $val], @vals);
    }
}

knapsack(46134_77, [], (
    125_00,  1000_00, 1039_36, 1171_60, 1200_00, 1320_00, 1680_00, 1757_20,
    1768_80, 1970_00, 2231_25, 2300_00, 2369_25, 2589_20, 2720_00, 2887_50,
    3000_00, 3085_00, 3142_60, 3174_40, 3742_70, 3847_20, 5609_25, 5881_05,
    12240_48, 14112_00, 29318_07, 32551_80,
));
```

Note that I've converted your decimal values to integers (by multiplying them all by 100), as floating-point comparisons are a minefield. (See [*What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for details.)

Answer (score 1):

Read other answers/comments first. Here is a solution that could be used for a *small* set of data.

```
double[] nums = new double[] { 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,150,200,250,300,400,500};

Parallel.ForEach(GetIndexes(nums.Length), list =>
{
    if (list.Select(n => nums[n]).Sum()==350)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(list.Aggregate("", (s, n) => s += nums[n] + " "));
    }
});

IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GetIndexes(int count)
{
    for (ulong l = 0; l < Math.Pow(2, count); l++)
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        BitArray bits = new BitArray(BitConverter.GetBytes(l));
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(ulong)*8; i++)
        {
            if (bits.Get(i)) list.Add(i);
        }
        yield return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution only works if you use each of the numbers in the list only once.  for example it wont find 20 in nums = {10}

Answer (score 0):

Yes duskwuff is right. The ONLY combination that adds up to 46134.77
is this one:

125
1,000.00
1,320.00
2,231.25
3,085.00
3,174.40
5,881.05
29,318.07

It took 2 seconds to find out. I have used SumMatch Excel add-in.